# Can't match tuple inside of foldl

Tags: haskell, fold

I have the following code, which should™ convert an excel column type its corresponding number. For example AA into 27 and AB into 28:

```
import Data.Char (ord)
import Data.List (foldl1')

columnToNumber :: String -> Int
columnToNumber s = foldl1' (\acc (i, v) -> acc + 26 ^ i * v) (values s)
  where values s = zip (reverse [0..(length s)]) ((\c -> ord c - 64) <$> s)
```

The idea is to take the string "AA" convert it to the corresponding numbers

```
["A", "A"] -> [1, 1]
```

and zip it with the base so from right to left 26^0, 26^1, 26^2, and so on.

```
zip [1, 0] [1, 1] -> [(1, 1), (0, 1)]
```

That way the result of the fold would be

```
26^1 * 1 + 26^0 * 1 = 27
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following errors and I'm not sure why:

```
ExcelSheetColumn.hs:7:34:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
                with actual type ‘(Integer, Int)’
    In the pattern: (i, v)
    In the first argument of ‘foldl1'’, namely
      ‘(\ acc (i, v) -> acc + 26 ^ i * v)’
    In the expression:
      foldl1' (\ acc (i, v) -> acc + 26 ^ i * v) (values s)

ExcelSheetColumn.hs:7:63:
    Couldn't match type ‘(Int, Int)’ with ‘Int’
    Expected type: [Int]
      Actual type: [(Int, Int)]
    In the second argument of ‘foldl1'’, namely ‘(values s)’
    In the expression:
      foldl1' (\ acc (i, v) -> acc + 26 ^ i * v) (values s)
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Well first I think you want to use `length s - 1` in your values function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to get it compiling you actually just have to switch `foldl1'` to `foldl'` and add the *starting* accumulator:

```
import Data.Char (ord)
import Data.List (foldl')

columnToNumber :: String -> Int
columnToNumber s = foldl' (\acc (i, v) -> acc + 26 ^ i * v) 0 (values s)
  where values s = zip (reverse [0..(length s)]) ((\c -> ord c - 64) <$> s)
```

if you add the suggestion `Free_D` made (start at `length s - 1`):

```
columnToNumber :: String -> Int
columnToNumber s = foldl' (\acc (i, v) -> acc + 26 ^ i * v) 0 (values s)
  where values s = zip (reverse [0..(length s -1)]) ((\c -> ord c - 64) <$> s)
```

you get the desired results:

```
λ> columnToNumber "AA"
27
λ> columnToNumber "AB"
28
```

---

I don't know if you actually gonna need this but hey why not:

what you probably don't like is that `columnToNumber "A1"` is `11` - to fix this you need to tread digits differently from letters:

```
columnToNumber :: String -> Int
columnToNumber s = foldl' (\acc (i, v) -> acc + 26 ^ i * v) 0 (values s)
  where values s = zip (reverse [0..(length s -1)]) (parse <$> s)
        parse c
          | c >= '0' && c <= '9' = ord c - ord '0'
          | otherwise = ord c - 64
```

Comment: Ah foldl1 -> foldl was so simple.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the definition of `foldl1'`, it has to take two things that are of the same type and produce something similar

```
*Main Data.List> :t foldl1'
foldl1' :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

But `foldl` is what you want:

```
*Main Data.List> :t foldl
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

So essentially this:

```
import Data.Char (ord, toUpper)

columnToNumber :: String -> Int
columnToNumber s = foldl (\acc (i, v) -> acc + 26 ^ i * v) 0 $ values s where 
    values s = zip [l - 1, l - 2 ..0] ((\c -> (ord.toUpper) c - 64) <$> s) where
        l = length s
```

Comment: `[l - 1, l - 2 ..0]` had no idea you could do this!